# Refactoring my angular code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring

I have a code here, where I used in there different controller. I thought of shifting this code to a factory but unable to do so. I'll explain more clearly. Below is my code.

```
scope.countDown     = 4;
scope.runCounter = function() {
            scope.countDown -= 1;            
            if ( scope.countDown > 0) timeout(scope.runCounter, 1000);              
            else scope.loginUser(); //can be different function
        };
```

What it does is just a countdown timer. When the countdown hit to 0 it will call a scope function. As far as my re factoring go I have this:

my factory:

```
runCounter : function(countDown, callback) {
        rootScope.countDown = countDown;
        var self = this;

        rootScope.countDown -= 1;            
        if ( rootScope.countDown > 0) timeout(self.runCounter, 1000);              
        // else callback();
      }
```

I dont know how to pass a function inside my factory function. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but this is a standard use case for `$timeout` service.

`$timeout(myfunction,noOfSeconds * 1000);`

in your case

`$timeout(scope.loginUser,4 * 1000);`

See [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)

**Update**
You can do something like

```
runCounter : function(countDown, callback) {
    $timeout(callback,countDown* 1000);      
}
```

Comment: my main problem is how to convert my code in the controller into factory? Since I'm using the runCounter in there different controllers.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it works but how would you display the counter/countDown?